# Scaling an iFrame depending on window size and content size

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have a dynamically generated iFrame on my page that loads a website using a variable object.

All that is well understood. My challenge now is that in some cases, say if I am viewing on mobile, the frame width exceeds my mobile device width.

```js
// STATIC VALUE
let screenSize = {
    "height": window.innerHeight,
    "width" window.innerWidth:
}
// DYNAMICALLY GENERATED VARIABLE
let frameValue = {
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "height": 913,
    "width": 1600
}

//Using this variable, the iframe property is set as follows using javascript
$('#dynamicFrame').attr('src', frameValue.url);
$('#dynamicFrame').width(frameValue.width);
$('#dynamicFrame').height(frameValue.height);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML DYNAMIC iFRAME -->
<iframe src="" id="dynamicFrame" frameBorder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto"> </iframe>
```

Need:
I would like an algorithm (or perhaps some code) to perhaps scale or zoom the iframe whilst keeping its aspect ratio.

Meaning I want the content to of frameValue.url (example.com) to load in the iframe as it would while considering frameValue.width & frameValue.height.

Notes:
I don't mind having the iframe look smaller or have dark bands around the edge just like when you watch videos on a mobile device or use zoom or Microsoft teams on a mobile device whilst the person sharing the screen is on a desktop device.

Please feel free to comment if you need further explanation. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication

Comment: When you say you want to adapt this regarding the width, then the desktop _height_ is irrelevant at this point. // When you have two tuples of values, and the ratio between the values in each tuple is the same - then cross multiplication allows you to determine the "missing" 4th value, based on the values you _have_ for the other three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the screen size and orientation, one of the following formulas may be useful.
NB:The orientation can be determined using the dimensions provided. i.e landcape = width > height

```
let scale = 0;
// If the window is potrait and the frame is landscape orientation
scale = screenSize.height * (1 / frameValue.height);
// If the window is landscape and the frame is potrait, one of the following applies.
scale = dimensions.height/dimensions.width).toFixed(2);
// OR
scale = dimensions.width/dimensions.height).toFixed(2);

// Set the iFrame Dynamic Scale Value
iframe.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you aren't using a CSS solution? It'd be a much cleaner solution than setting the height/width attributes.

```css
#dynamicFrame {
  /* Swap for your desired aspect ratio */
  aspect-ratio 16/9;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe the use case may vary.
The iframe variable size could be mobile while the window size may be desktop. Also all these devices have different screen sizes and aspect ratios and so i can not have an hard coded value. It has to be dynamic.